# Finding longest concatenated word

Tags: java, string

I have a dictionary with many words. And i hope search the longest concatenated word (that is, the longest word that is comprised entirely of
shorter words in the file). I give the method a descending word from their length. How can I check that all the symbols have been used from the dictionary?

```
 public boolean tryMatch(String s, List dictionary) {
    String nextWord = new String();
    int contaned = 0;

    //Цикл перебирающий каждое слово словаря
        for(int i = 1; i < dictionary.size();i++) {

            nextWord = (String) dictionary.get(i);
            if (nextWord == s) {
                nextWord = (String) dictionary.get(i + 1);
            }

            if (s.contains(nextWord)) {

                contaned++;
            }

        }

    if(contaned >1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==`.

Comment: Some background information to @Marvin's comment: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) (this is not only valid for `String`s, but for any kind of object in Java).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a sorted list of words, finding compound words is easy, but it will only perform well if the words are in a `Set`.

Let's look at the compound word `football`, and of course assume that both `ball` and `foot` are in the work list.

By definition, any compound word using `foot` as the first sub-word must start with foot.

So, when iterating the list, remember the current active "stem" words, e.g. when seeing `foot`, remember it.

Now, when seeing `football`, you check if the word starts with the stem word. If not, clear the stem word, and make new word the stem word.

If it does, the new word (`football`) is a candidate for being a compound word. The part after the stem is `ball`, so we need to check if that is a word, and if so, we found a compound word.

Checking is easy for simple case, i.e. `wordSet.contains(remain)`.

However, compound words can be made up of more than 2 words, e.g. `whatsoever`. So after finding that it is a candidate from the stem word `what`, the remain is `soever`.

You can simply try all lengths of that (`soever`, `soeve`, `soev`, `soe`, `so`, `s`), and if one of the shorter ones are words, you repeat the process.